# Aptana automatically open javaw.exe file

Tags: aptana

Every time i open Aptana , automatically open javaw.exe file.
I close this file then rerun aptana also open javaw.exe.

how can i stop it?

thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlM09.png)

Comment: Maybe the app opens last viewed file or recent ones. Find somewhere in `File` those files(usually they're listed there) and delete them. If it doesn't help, open some settings/preferences for that app and uncheck open last session or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the response. but There is no delete them.